# Trying to use same component with different templates

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, components, ionic4, angular8

I am trying to use a `component` in 2 different places in the application but I want to change the `template` and keep the **functionality**.

---

- In one case I want to use the `component` as a `button`.
- In the other case, I want to use the `component` as a `list item`.

---

Everything is the same Just the `template` change, and I was wondering if there is any way to do it without using an if inside just by extending the `component` or something cleaner.

Some code:

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="status">

  <button *ngSwitchCase="'none'" (click)="action()">
    <ion-icon name="md-white-users"></ion-icon>
    Ask to connect
  </button>
  <button *ngSwitchCase="'requestSent'" class="connected">
    <ion-icon name="md-white-users"></ion-icon>
    Request Sent
  </button>
  <button *ngSwitchCase="'connected'" class="connected">
    <ion-icon name="md-white-users"></ion-icon>
    Connected
  </button>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try `<ng-content>` [(Content Projection)](https://dev.to/angular/understanding-content-projection-in-angular-2ld9)

**Your component's template:**

```html
<ng-content> </ng-content>
```

**Other component where you instantiate the previous component:**

```html
<app-my-dynamic-component>
  <!-- Button's template -->
</app-my-dynamic-component>

<app-my-dynamic-component>
  <!-- List's template -->
</app-my-dynamic-component>
```

This is assuming your component doesn't rely heavily on the template because I don't really know how template variables are handled inside `<ng-content>`.